# Swagger Editor: How to define simple response string and redirect

Tags: api, swagger

Defining responses in swagger is easy:

```
  responses:
    # Response code
    200:
      description: Successful response
      schema:
        title: OK
        type: array
        items:
          title: Person
          type: object
          properties:
            name:
              type: string
            single:
              type: boolean
```

1. How I can return simple string and not an array
2. What if API endpoint makes a redirect, actually in my case redirecting is the successful attempt.

   > Let's skip the fact that redirecting in an API is a non-professional thing!

**Update**: Responding with a string is easy too:

```
description: A simple string response
schema:
  type: string
```

Comment: Its better to define schema under `definitions:` and refer to schema like 
`schema: $ref: "#/definitions/User"`.
It's better to study their pet-store example - go to http://editor.swagger.io/ and open example `perstore_full.yaml` - which is equivalent to http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml

I am guessing you have answered your own question in your update?

Comment: Update is an answer for item 1, what about item 2? Is it possible to define a redirect in a swagger response?

Comment: Redirect is usually done by server. If you are designing API for new system, and you know end point will be redirected why not define the API where it's supposed to end up after redirection? 

If that is not possible, just define API for endpoint without redirection, and tell HTTP client library to follow redirection (by default this should be enabled in most HTTP client).

Comment: In my case, a request arrives and it should get redirected with proper tokens. No access to incoming request, it is what it is!